# Windows 8.1 Emulator does not exist

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have a Windows 8.1 Pro 64bit installed with Visual Studio 2013 Update 4.

I tried to deploy the app on my device and it was successful. Yesterday, i tried to run the app on emulator and facing some problems.

I downloaded the emulator from [Windows Phone 8.1 Update and Emulator](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43719)

Download contains two files. I tried to install the SDK & Emulation images and setup completed without any problem.

Now visual studio is showing the list of emulators in IDE but whenever i tried to run the app using emulator, VS gave me error as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Emulation\Images\flash.update1.vhd does not exist`. I checked the location and found no .vhd file.

Already tried to repair the installation with administrative privileges but that didn't worked.

Anyone have any idea what might be the problem and how to solve this ?

Comment: You may have to uninstall VS 2013, remove any left overs and re-install from scratch.

Comment: Ok. I did uninstall the SDK but it looks like i have to uninstall the VS too

Comment: Yes, everything. It's time consuming, but it worked before when I've had issues with VS, updates and emulators.

Comment: Thanks. I'll post my experience after re-installation. :)

Comment: @NeilTurner :  Same error even after Re-installation of VS and SDK with admin privileges.

Comment: Go to Tools->Extensions and Updates and check your update section and update to latest updates or get the latest emulator from https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/download-phone-sdk

Comment: Already tried. My VS is updated and i have latest emulator. I have Windows Phone 8.1 Update 1 Emulators already installed Still not works

Comment: As a development in this process, Re-installation of a Operating System (Windows 8.1 Pro 64Bit) doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Go to
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394354
That will start a download of a windowsphone81sdkupdate1.exe
Run this program, choose "Repair". Fixed. At least, it did for me.

Answer (score -1):

This trick worked for me.

Go to Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Emulation\Images\flash.vhd"
Rename "flash.vhd" to "flash.update1.vhd"