# Windows 8.1 Emulator not found: flash.vhd v flash.update1.vhd

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have a Windows 10 PC and I am trying to create my first Windows Phone app.  I have installed the Visual Studio 2015 Communiuty Edition and the Emulators.  I get an error when I clcik on the Debug (Emulator) button in Visual Studio:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Emulation\Images\flash.vhd does not exist

I have looked in the location above and flash.vhd does not exist, however flash.update1.vhd does exist.  What is the difference between flash.vhd and flash.update1.vhd? I am guessing that flash.update1.vhd is flash.vhd with update 1!? How can I configure Visual Studio to use flash.update1.vhd instead of flash.vhd?

I have read a few other questions e.g. this one: [Windows 8.1 Emulator does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30119607/windows-8-1-emulator-does-not-exist).  However, I have not found my answer.

Comment: I have the same problem. Maybe it's because I have Windows 10 Home only.